# What is better to use predicates or relationships in Core-Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have surfed the internet, but after some hours haven't realized if it's better to use predicates or relationships to fetch data in order to obtain the best performance. This is my scenario, suppose I have two Entities `Entity A` and `Entity B` and `Entity A` has a *one-to-many* relationship with `Entity B`. `Entity A -->> Entity B`

Both get their information from a web service, then using the **relationships option**, I first get the information from the Entity , fill the `Entity B` and when I fill `Entity A` I need to perform a fetching from `Entity B` that have the relationship with my `Entity A` (this for every record in my `Entity A`) suppose for an *id field,* and every match have to be added to the core-data relationship.

In the other hand, that is **without relationship**, I just need to fill both Entities and when I need the records related to `Entity A` from `Entity B` just perform a fetch request with a **predicate** referring to the *id field* and that's all.

At first glance it seems that the first case that is **using references** is **less efficient**, but I do not know if the use of relationships has a superior performance for subsequent searches and the overall operation of the application.

I hope someone can help me to clarify my doubt. Thank you

Comment: If you have way too many properties and don't always need everything, and are planning to use more relationships in the future, use two relationships. Otherwise, go with one object only. "Performance" should be measured. Is 0.01 seconds too much of a performance break for you? Or maybe you are importing millions of objects ? Who knows. What have you tried so far . and why don't you just create an empty project and test it out with your specific use-case?

Comment: Thank you for your response Sneak, well my intention with the question is to know the benefits of relationships in coredata, I haven't made a proof creating a project and testing both cases as you said because I think the first case will take more time due to the fetching and adding process. Being more specific my table A will contain a maximum of 1k records but my table B can hold at least 100k

Comment: I see. Well, the ammount of items your table holds is not the most important since iOS/CoreData and NSFetchedResultsController does the memory managment for you. Unless you manually do all those stuff without NSFCtrl.   Even if you have many properties in an object without relationships, you can specify what properties to fetch to avoid using more memory than you need. You should read about faulting: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html . Also, I suggest you don't focus on the "performance" but rather your structure...

Comment: .. That is, how do you maintain a good structure in your CoreData graph, in  case you expand the structure with relationships, it is better to have a "clean" structure plan rather than getting stuck on the performance part, because if you do everything according to the documentations , the performance gains from what you are asking are not noticable, if any at all. Read more about fetching specific properties here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedpropertydescription

Comment: I edited your post, since you refer to CoreData entities as "Table" it got me really confused thinking you were talking about TableViews, and you will confuse yourself too and make wrong choises if you see CoreData as a Database. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599599/core-data-is-not-a-relational-database-why-exactly-is-this-important-to-know

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar experience with a chat app.  Each message in a chat and a chat can have many many messages (over a 1000 is common).  I wanted to find every message of a certain type (all video messages for example).  Running a fetch request for on Messages was 10 to 100 times SLOWER than running the predicate on the relationship.

Relationships are really fast compared to fetchRequests.